# Как вытащить атрибут title у select и поместить в span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Прочесть атрибут title у select, поместить в переменную.
2. Создать под тем же select разметку со span и присвоить значение переменной взятой у тайтла селекта.

   ```
       <select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку">
           <optgroup label="">
               <option value="AK">Hundai</option>
               <option value="HI">Hundai</option>
               <option value="CA">Hundai</option>
           </optgroup>
       </select>
   ```

**Результат, которого ожидаю:**

```js
$('<span/>', {class: 'select-title', text: $('select').attr('title')}).insertAfter('select');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку">
    <optgroup label="">
        <option value="AK">Hundai</option>
        <option value="HI">Hundai</option>
        <option value="CA">Hundai</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку2">
    <optgroup label="">
        <option value="AK">Hundai</option>
        <option value="HI">Hundai</option>
        <option value="CA">Hundai</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку3">
    <optgroup label="">
        <option value="AK">Hundai</option>
        <option value="HI">Hundai</option>
        <option value="CA">Hundai</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку4">
    <optgroup label="">
        <option value="AK">Hundai</option>
        <option value="HI">Hundai</option>
        <option value="CA">Hundai</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: эм.... `$('.select-title').text($('.form-control').attr('title'));` ..... только `Выберите Марку` обычно помещают самым первым `option` в селекте... а не в `title`...

Comment: Спасибо большое работает.
Однако, есть нюанс, по умолчанию span нет на страницы, мне бы хотелось бы его создать вместе со значением!

Comment: Ну значит надо почитать как на jquery создавать элемент, добавлять текст и добавить элемент в тело)) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ как пример `var spanEl = $("<span></span>").text($('.form-control').attr('title')); 
    $("body").append(spanEl);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так.

```js
$('select').each(function(){
   var $thisSelect = $(this);
   $('<span/>', {class: 'select-title', text: $thisSelect.attr('title')}).insertAfter(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <select class="form-control" title="Выберите Марку">
        <optgroup label="">
            <option value="AK">Hundai AK</option>
            <option value="HI">Hundai HI</option>
            <option value="CA">Hundai CA</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

   <select class="form-control" title="Не Выберите Марку">
        <optgroup label="">
            <option value="AK">Hundai AK</option>
            <option value="HI">Hundai HI</option>
            <option value="CA">Hundai CA</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: Супер, работает, однако, есть нюансан, по умолчанию span нет на страницы, мне бы хотелось бы его создать вместе со значением!

Comment: Обновил ответ, пробуйте. Но данный код будет правильно работать только если будет один select на странице если их будет больше, то код нужно менять.

Comment: Вот вот, а у меня их много, как быть? помогите и на этот раз

Comment: Не хочу показаться грубым, сколько вы готовы заплатить за написание для вас рабочего скрипта? )))) Обновил ответ